# regex get sentences that end with a question mark

Tags: java, regex

I got a big file with all my email activity over the last 5 years.
I would like to get all my sentences back that have a question mark.
I'm not good with regex, i just know a bit of what can be done.

Could someone give me a regex that would work? (java)

If it's possible then i would like to return the bold in the next example:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed amet elementum. **Integer nec diam erat, eu consectetur nibh?** Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    String str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
            + "My second question? Sed amet elementum."
            + "Integer nec diam erat, eu consectetur nibh?"
            + "Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^.?!]*)\\?");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

It outputs:

```
My second question?
Integer nec diam erat, eu consectetur nibh?
```

Here I define sentence ending as `.`, `!` or `?` but you can extend that list easily.

Comment: ^ means that you will match all characters except the once listed afterwards. You use \\ to escape the ?, meaning you are really interested in the character question mark (otherwise ? means the preceding item is optional).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression like: `[^.!?]+\?`

This would match the desired text in your example at least.